# Pipelining a set of C buffers

Tags: c, buffer

I am creating Ethernet packets in an embedded system. I have my Data / IP and UDP packet headers defined in pre-allocated buffers and I have a large buffer that is used to grab data from the FPGA's fabric using DMA.

I also have some user data headers and footers where the data comes from the fabric in other ways, mostly SPI transfer of temperature, PCB address etc. Or even grabs of some of the configuration registers (single transaction, on-boot).

Now, at the moment I concatenate these using memcpy into a new larger buffer (also pre-allocated), and then send to the Transmit buffer of the on-FPGA MAC.

My issues:
1) All these buffers are on the FPGA hence requiring memory, I could copy them one at a time into the MAC Tx buffer but this would prevent my second idea.
2) All being buffers, gives the possibility of forming a pipeline, where new data (DN+1) can be put into the first buffers, while subsequent buffers are storing and concatenating the data of (DN+0).

If I have a nice modularised code, how do I create a pipeline from buffer to buffer. In hardware I'd use flags, only passing data from Buffer A to B when Buffer B has finished passing its data to C. In terms of C, memcpy and memmove return only void, I'd therefore need to make my own boolean flag that is modified after memcpy finishes *and* I'd need to make these flags globals so that I can easily pass their status into other functions.

Finally, as this is embedded, I don't have access to the full C libraries and both time and memory are at a premium.

Thanks
Ed

Comment: If you are talking about buffers in memory, you shouldn't `memcpy/memmove` from one buffer to another. Instead you should just pass pointers around, i.e. when moving from B to C you'll just give C a pointer to the buffer currently held by B (and remove the pointer from B).

Comment: That might work fine for a single buffer, however my MAC TX buffer requires a pointer to a buffer, where that datais made up of: i) packet header, ii) user header, iii) DMA obtained data and iv) user footer. I could change the lowest level MAC Tx buffer writing function to grab these separately, however a) that defeats the object of using function libraries and b) each transaction would need its own overhead, whereas with buffers I should be able to pipeline so that new data is coming into the first buffers while data is being moved from the main buffer to the MAC Tx buffer.